# C ++ operator overload ++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

which one of the two codes is right and why ?

```
C C::operator++() {
    x++; 
    y++; 
    return *this; 
}


C & C::operator++() {
    x++; 
    y++; 
    return *this; 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What happened when you tested both of those yourself?

Comment: They both seem to work fine, but I don't know which one is right

Comment: The reference return is "correct" (its an lvalue thing). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719) and scroll down to the appropriate subsection.

Comment: I would optate for the second (&C return)

Comment: As comments and answers mentiom, the second is "more" correct. PS: to whomever downvoted the question, please mention why. It's a well-formed and interesting question and does not deserve a negative score.

Comment: Maybe the question was downvoted because it doesn't show any research effort

Comment: This is not a question about research, as use of `&` is a point of contention, especially in examples like above. Also, consider the OP's second post in which he said that he compiled both but wasn't sure which one is correct -- given that the answer is nontrivial (and involved in the muddy topic known as idiomatic C++ and lvalue/rvalue semantics), I'd say OP did as much research as would be required before asking the question. I guess I'm just a bit irked at SO's recent "reddit mentality" of downvote first, ask questions later.

Comment: While baking one's noodle on these, you can add in thoughts on `C& operator ++()&;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second one is the idiomatic one: a parameter-less `operator++` is the pre-fix increment operator, which should return a reference to self.

Comment: Which function is prefix: `operator(int)++` or `operator()++`? I know one of them takes a parameter: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?231051-C-Operator-How-to-overload-postfix-increment-and-decrement-operators

Comment: @ThomasMatthews the one I said in my answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

Both are "correct", but the second is idiomatic, because it's expected that the prefix `operator ++` returns an lvalue.